# How to create a clipboard object in GTK using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linux, gtk, gnome

I'm having a dickens of a time creating a clipboard object in JavaScript.

```
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;

// A bunch of unimportant code

var clippy = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.Atom.intern("CLIPBOARD", false)); // Hi clippy
clippy.request_text(this._textRec);

// And elsewhere this._textRec is defined as...
_textRec: function(clipboard, text, data) {
    this.label.label = text;
}
```

With the above code, I get the error "Can't create a Javascript object for Atom; no way to copy". Thoughts? Suggestions? I'm very new to GTK programming, and I'm not sure how different the JS stuff is from, say, the python information available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the time of writing.

Here is a link to the bug report about it: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579312